# C# LINQ query foreign key loops

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

In my MySQL database I have three tables where, both Items and innerItems have images. So in images table rows either innerItem_id or itemId is not null but not both.

```
CREATE TABLE `Item` (
  `itemId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` longtext,
  `description` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`itemId`))

CREATE TABLE `InnerItem` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` longtext,
  `description` longtext,
  `itemId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_InnerItem_Item_itemId` FOREIGN KEY (`itemId`) REFERENCES `Item` (`itemId`)
) 

CREATE TABLE `Images` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` longtext,
  `innerItem_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `itemId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Images_Item_itemId` FOREIGN KEY (`itemId`) REFERENCES `Item` (`itemId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Images_InnerItem_innerItem_id` FOREIGN KEY (`innerItem_id`) REFERENCES `Products` (`id`)
)
```

I am using C# LINQ to query the database,

```
var records = db.items.Where (p => p.name== name).Select (entity => 
                        new {
                            id = entity.itemId,
                            name = entity.name,
                            description = entity.description,
                            images = entity.images.Select (img => new
                                {
                                    id = img.id,
                                    url = img.url
                                }),
                            innerItems= entity.innerItems.Select(item => new {
                                id = item.id,
                                description = item.description,
                                name = item.name,
                                images = item.images.Select (img => new
                                    {
                                        id = img.id,
                                        url = "images" + "/" + img.uuid + ".jpg",
                                        uuid = img.uuid
                                    }),
                            })

                        }).ToList ();
```

When exceuting the linq query I get below error,

```
Error              - System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unknown column 'Join3.itemId' in 'on clause'
```

Any idea on this?

UPDATE

Data model classes

```
public class Item{
        public Item() {
            images = new List<Image>();
            innerItems= new List<InnerItem>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int itemId{get;set;}
        public string name {get;set;}
        public string description {get;set;}
        public virtual ICollection<Image> images {get;set;}
        public virtual ICollection<InnerItem> innerItems{get;set;} //Has many

            }
public class InnerItem{
        public InnerItem() {
            images = new List<Image>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int id {get;set;}
        public string name {get;set;}
        public string description {get;set;}
        public virtual ICollection<Image> images {get;set;}

        public virtual Item item{get;set;} //many-to-one

    }

public class Image {
        [Key]
        public int id {get;set;}
        public string url {get;set;}
        //Either one
        [ForeignKey("item")]
        public int? itemId{ get; set;}
        [ForeignKey("itemId")]
        public virtual Item item{get;set;} //many-to-one
        [ForeignKey("innerItem")]
        public int? innerItem_id { get; set;}
        [ForeignKey("innerItem_id")]
        public virtual InnerItem innerItem{get;set;} //many-to-one

    }
```

Comment: Is this an already created database, or do you have authority to change the data model?

Comment: it is a already created database. But I can do changes in the model

Comment: please explain id why only id , it should be item id everywhere

Comment: Yes, for the item table, it is as itemId, I have edited it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have permission to change the data model, I'd suggest the following:

Your `Item` and `InnerItem` tables are identical, except for a Foreign Key relationship (`InnerItem` => `Item`), representing a parent, which would be null if the `Item` lacked a parent. This would simplify `Images` and greatly simplify this and other queries moving moving forward. Your database scheme would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Item` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` longtext,
  `description` longtext,
  `parentItemId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Item_to_parent_itemId` FOREIGN KEY (`parentItemId`) REFERENCES `Item` (`id`)
) 

CREATE TABLE `Images` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` longtext,
  `itemId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Images_Item_itemId` FOREIGN KEY (`itemId`) REFERENCES `Item` (`Id`),
)
```

This way you only need a single constraint, and you don't need to code in the logic to handle if an `Image` entry was intended for an inner image or a normal image. As before stated, all you need to do to determine if something is a top-most item is to just check if the `parentItemId` field is null. *Further* this structure allows you to then nest items deeper than a top level and once deeper if you ever need to do that.

Comment: Opps sorry I have simplified the tables here. but they have more fields in real.

Comment: @Diluu Okay, fair enough. I'll try to debug the code you have and update my answer. Could you post the C# definition of "items" and "innerItems" as used by d.items? I want to see how the C# class association between Item and InnerItem.

Comment: Thanks @Nex Terrn, i have updated the question with class definitions.